# How to clear duplicate values off from UNION of two tables?

Tags: sql, soql

I would appreciate a little help!

The real code looks much uglier with all the conditions, so this should be sufficient:

```
SELECT
Column1 AS FIRST_COL, 
Column2 AS SECOND_COL, 
Column3 AS THIRD_COL, 
Column4 AS FOURTH_COL, 
Phone AS PHONE, 
Column6 AS SIXTH_COl,
FROM Standard_Table
WHERE Column01 = 'xy01'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
FIRST_COL,
SECOND_COL,
THIRD_COL,
FOURTH_COL,
PHONE,
SIXTH_COL,
FROM Special_Table
WHERE COLUMN01 = 'xy'
```

The thing is I'd like to get rid of the duplicate users based on their **phone numbers** (PHONE column).
Some of the users are in both tables, but their records are not consistent across the tables so DISTINCT won't work.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can select from the first table and then select *unmatched* rows from the second:

```
SELECT Column1 AS FIRST_COL,  Column2 AS SECOND_COL,  Column3 AS THIRD_COL, Column4 AS FOURTH_COL, 
       Phone AS PHONE, Column6 AS SIXTH_COl,
FROM Standard_Table
WHERE Column01 = 'xy01'
UNION ALL
SELECT FIRST_COL, SECOND_COL, THIRD_COL, FOURTH_COL,
       PHONE, SIXTH_COL,
FROM Special_Table sp
WHERE COLUMN01 = 'xy' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Standard_Table s
                  WHERE s.phone = sp.phone AND
                        s.Column01 = 'xy01'
                 );
```

Comment: @Amberjack . . . That would be because the phone is duplicated in one of the tables.

Comment: Okay, sorry. It might actually work, but the problem is that in my real query I'm using CASE WHEN on phone columns in order to edit them.

Comment: @Amberjack . . .  I think this answers the question you have asked here.  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries can be used in this cases. An extra condition can be added in the 2nd part as follows:

```
SELECT
Column1 AS FIRST_COL,
Column3 AS THIRD_COL, 
Column4 AS FOURTH_COL, 
Phone AS PHONE, 
Column6 AS SIXTH_COl,
FROM Standard_Table
WHERE Column01 = 'xy01'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
FIRST_COL,
SECOND_COL,
THIRD_COL,
FOURTH_COL,
PHONE,
SIXTH_COL,
FROM Special_Table
WHERE COLUMN01 = 'xy' AND 
PHONE NOT IN (
  SELECT Phone
  FROM Standard_Table
);
```

Comment: This results only in rows from the Standard_table. The rows from the Special_Table are not returned at all.

Comment: Yes. It will only return values from the Special_Table if the phone number isn't already there in Standard_Table. Is that not what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will work for you

```
; WITH PartionedData AS (
    SELECT *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PHONE ORDER BY FIRST_COL) RowNum
    FROM (
        SELECT 
        Column1 AS FIRST_COL,
        Column3 AS THIRD_COL, 
        Column4 AS FOURTH_COL, 
        Phone AS PHONE, 
        Column6 AS SIXTH_COl,
        FROM Standard_Table
        WHERE Column01 = 'xy01'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        FIRST_COL,
        SECOND_COL,
        THIRD_COL,
        FOURTH_COL,
        PHONE,
        SIXTH_COL,
        FROM Special_Table
        WHERE COLUMN01 = 'xy' AND 
        PHONE NOT IN (
          SELECT Phone
          FROM Standard_Table
        ) CombinedData
)
SELECT 
FIRST_COL,
THIRD_COL, 
FOURTH_COL, 
PHONE, 
SIXTH_COl,
FROM PartionedData
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Though both UNION and UNION ALL is used to combine results of two SELECT queries, the main difference between them is that UNION doesn't include duplicate record but UNION ALL does. Another difference between them is that UNION ALL is faster than UNION but may look slow because it returns more data which takes more time to travel via the network.

So you may try using UNION